# How to truncate the text and highlight search keyword when the text is too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I am using `Ransack` `gem` for a search functionality in my `Rails` application. I am highlighting the search keyword param : `params[:search]` in the search results. I have successfully done it with the `highlight` helper method

```
<%= highlight(@description.slice(0..50), params[:search]) %>
```

This works fine if the keyword occurs between the first `50` character of `@description`

But if the keyword occurs after 50 characters, how is it possible to highlight it with limiting the number of characters.

I have found a solution myself and added it as the answer. Is there any other efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`excerpt` helper method can be used to extract the text that matches the first instance of a phrase.

```
<%= highlight(excerpt(@description, params[:search], radius: 50), params[:search]) %>
```

More details on `TextHelper`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html